# Javascript public namespace functions not defined when deployed

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I've got the scripts below that I am assigning to a public Javascript namespace. They all work fine locally, I can call `TEST.loading(true)` and all behaves as expected, however when I deploy them up to my remote server, I am getting the following error in Chrome/Firefox console; ***Uncaught TypeError: TEST.loading is not a function***

I can't figure out why it would work locally and not remotely. I don't think this would make any difference, but I am using MVC bundles to deploy the scripts and I have checked the network output from Chrome and the scripts are being loaded fine and I can see the code inside....any advice?

```
var TEST = TEST || 
{
    dtFormat: "DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm",

    loading: function loading(showLoading) {
        if (showLoading) {
            if (Modernizr.cssanimations)
                $("#loadingAnimation").show();
            else
                $("#loadingStatic").show();
            $("#loadingContainer").show();
        }
        else {
            if (Modernizr.cssanimations)
                $("#loadingAnimation").hide();
            else
                $("#loadingStatic").hide();
            $("#loadingContainer").hide();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `TEST` exists before you're declaring this variable?

Comment: No, I've also tried with numerous other namespaces, always the same result, locally fine, remotely it seems to not like it

Comment: @Jak: The point is that if there's already a `TEST` defined, you won't add `loading` to the existing one. Your code above becomes a no-op.

Comment: Is there any reason to have `var TEST = TEST || {` in the first place, why not simply `var TEST = {`?

Comment: Do: `console.log(TEST);` Check the object before calling `loading`...

Comment: @MinusFour: Or better yet, set a breakpoint the `var TEST = ...` line and use the debugger to look around. No need for casting about in the dark with a `console.log` torch when you can turn on the lights.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek It seemed to be the suggested syntax in numerous articles I read, http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/ being one example

Comment: @Jak: The syntax above is only useful if your script is potentially being loaded twice. It's not useful if you have multiple modules that may add things to `TEST`.

Comment: Btw. what about `var m=showLoading?'show':'hide'` and then `$(%selector%)[m]()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that `TEST` is already defined with a truthy value when that code runs, making that code a no-op.

If you want to be sure to always add your properties, regardless of whether it's already there, this is the usual pattern:

```
var TEST = (function(t) {
{
    t.dtFormat = "DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm";

    t.loading = function loading(showLoading) {
        if (showLoading) {
            if (Modernizr.cssanimations)
                $("#loadingAnimation").show();
            else
                $("#loadingStatic").show();
            $("#loadingContainer").show();
        }
        else {
            if (Modernizr.cssanimations)
                $("#loadingAnimation").hide();
            else
                $("#loadingStatic").hide();
            $("#loadingContainer").hide();
        }
    };

    return t;
})(TEST || {});
```

This also has the advantage of giving you a handy scope for private functions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that, looks like it's fixed it nicely :)

Comment: @Jak: Cool. If it were me, I'd want to know why `TEST` was already defined with a truthy value in some situations, so definitely worth cracking out the debugger. Regards,

Comment: Looking through I think I've found another script that already had the TEST value set, I assume that this was causing some sort of conflict, but now I know how to fix it I can keep digging and sort it all out